# Problema al conectar a un repositorio por SSH

Tags: git

Desde hace un par de días, estoy configurando GIT en un servidor Linux mediante GitLab (que ya venía pre-instalado).

He creado un nuevo proyecto, y si me conecto por HTTP no tengo ningún problema. Lo hago a la siguiente dirección: http://192.168.1.33:10080/git/Probando.git

Sin embargo, cuando trato de conectarme vía SSH a la siguiente dirección: ssh://git@192.168.1.33:10022/git/Probando.git 
salta un mensaje de error que dice así:

> Incorrect credentials for repository at
>   ssh://192.168.1.33:10022/git/Probando.git

Creo que el problema está en las SSH Keys. He creado una clave y la he insertado, pero parece ser que no funciona. Os describo cómo la he creado e insertado:

1. Inicializo el repositorio:

   ```
   git init
   ```
2. Accedo a la siguiente ruta

   ```
   cd ~/.ssh
   ```
3. Genero la nueva clave utilizando el correo admin@example.com

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C 'admin@example.com'
   ```

   Cuando me dice que introduzca el nombre de un archivo, escribo **git_rsa**

   Cuando me dice **Enter passphrase** lo dejo en blanco (pulso enter)

   ```
   [~/.ssh] # ssh-keygen -t rsa -C 'admin@example.com'
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/share/homes/admin/.ssh/id_rsa): git_rsa
   git_rsa already exists.
   Overwrite (y/n)? y
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
   Enter same passphrase again:
   Your identification has been saved in git_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in git_rsa.pub.
   The key fingerprint is:
   SHA256:uiwCccsRLRC7IrTmRufRKi4O0LGsx7L8lcBqt1bOaX4 admin@example.com
   The key's randomart image is:
   +---[RSA 2048]----+
   |oo .             |
   | .o .            |
   |...o             |
   |o+=o.            |
   |=B+B .  S        |
   |Oo* +...         |
   |+Bo++oo          |
   |B++.+* E         |
   |++o+oo+          |
   +----[SHA256]-----+
   ```
4. Ahora imprimo la clave generada y la copio:

   ```
   cat git_rsa.pub
   ```

   Es algo así (borro un trozo por seguridad):

   ```
   ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC12zoBWILH38qY+hSLgPUwEChh2BdH9C/ydHP/EBBzm5nAJGRB.....................6IlE2RI4c/4iF1995oONG85yzy6sVEKe/qgRM0CGwrRNT00/491JjmdjZwvzVlii+5wdd4BUvHbn/N5Somt1XBVFtsPzhIetHgXKB admin@example.com
   ```
5. Voy a GitLab y abro la pestaña de SSH Keys

   - Pulso en ADD SSH KEY
   - Pego la clave copiada
   - Guardo los cambios
   - Se supone que la clave ya está insertada....
6. Pero cuando voy a entrar, introduzco la dirección SSH, usuario y contraseña (las mismas credenciales que para la conexión HTTP funciona correctamente) y me dice que las credenciales son incorrectas.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Cuando usa el comando ssh-keygen usted generá dos claves: una pública y una privada. La que copió aquí es pública (poco importa si elimina los carácteres). ¿Está seguro de haber añadido en Gitlab la llave pública y *no* la llave privada?

Comment: ¿Qué archivo es el contiene la clave privada?

Answer (score 5):

El problema está en que git no puede encontrar tu clave, ya que le estás poniendo un nombre que ssh no esta buscando. Cuando te conectas a un servidor usando ssh, tu pc le manda las llaves públicas que tiene disponibles (que busca en el directorio `~/.ssh` con los nombres usuales (`id_rsa.pub`, `id_dsa.pub`, etc), no puede saber cuales otros archivos son llaves públicas.

Para encontrar bien este tipo de errores, lo que conviene es intentar una conexión ssh con el nivel de verbose bien alto (para ver qué es lo que está fallando)

```
ssh -vvv 192.168.1.33:10022
```

Git lab no te va a dar accesso shell, igualmente, pero si tenés un error de autenticación vas a poder ver el detalle (como por ejemplo en este caso que llaves públicas estás presentando).

Para solucionar el problema lo que tenés que hacer es permitir que ssh encuentre tu clave ya sea usando un nombre común para eso (y el directorio correcto) o sea copiando tu clave privada en `~/.ssh/id_rsa` y la pública en `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` o agregando la llave esa al agente de ssh (`ssh-agent`) con el comando: `ssh-add git_rsa`.

#### Update

Al parecer, también se puede indicar nombres de archivo adicional que ssh va a buscar agregando en el archivo `~/.ssh/config` (que puede ser creado al efecto):

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa
```

De esta manera, no es necesario usar el ssh-agent (y por lo tanto tampoco se usa `ssh-add`)

Comment: Al tratarse de un servidor QNAP no dispongo del comando ssh-add

Comment: Ponle entonces un nombre estándar. `ssh-add` tendrás que usarlo si usas algún nombre no estándar.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con un nombre estándar?

Comment: @Pedro la lista sería: "~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
     ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/identity." según el manual.

Comment: @Pedro que es un servidor QNAP? o mejor dicho, el comando lo `ssh-add` lo tenés que usar en tu computadora local. Si no tenés `ssh-add` tenés que: o usar uno de los nombres estándar (para que ssh encuentre tu clave fácil) o configurar git para que use una configuración específica de ssh o configurar ssh para que encuentre tu clave. (`man git-config` y `man ssh_config`).

Comment: @Pedro Esta bueno marcar como correcta una respuesta si alguna solucionó tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que todo es correcto siguiendo la documentacion de GitLab http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html, por eso te recomendaria que verificaras los que tiene los siguientes permisos en las siguientes rutas:

- 0711 en /home/$TU_USUARIO
- 0700 en /home/$TU_USUARIO/.ssh
- 0600 en /home/$TU_USUARIO/.ssh/authorized_keys

Además, verifica que en el fichero de configuración de ssh situado en **~/.ssh/config** busca las claves publicas en la ruta donde tu las has añadido.

Comment: Verificado, en principio parece que todos los permisos son correctos...